error during connect: Post http://docker:2375/v1.40/auth: dial tcp: lookup docker on 192.168.0.1:53: no such host
Trying to run the local gitlab runner with docker executor for running the ci pipeline jobs  with 'linux' tag
following is .gitlabci.yml
stages:
  - build

variables:
  CONTAINER_COMMIT_IMAGE: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
  PYTHON_TEST_IMAGE: python:3.7-alpine
  DOCKER_IMAGE: docker:19.03.1
  DIND_IMAGE: $DOCKER_IMAGE-dind
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""

web:
  stage: build
  image: $DOCKER_IMAGE
  tags:
    - linux
  services:
    - $DIND_IMAGE
  before_script:
    - echo $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD | docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER $CI_REGISTRY --password-stdin
  script:
    - docker build --build-arg GITLAB_CI_TOKEN=$GITLAB_CI_TOKEN --pull -t $CONTAINER_COMMIT_IMAGE-web .
    - docker push $CONTAINER_COMMIT_IMAGE-web
  when: manual

following is the gitlab-runner config file config.toml
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0
connection_max_age = "15m0s"
shutdown_timeout = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "docker-runner"
  url = "https://gitlab.com/"
  id = xxxxx
  token = "<GITLAB_TOKEN>"
  token_obtained_at = 2024-05-07T11:28:16Z
  token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    MaxUploadedArchiveSize = 0
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:stable"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock", "/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
    network_mtu = 0

when I run the CI job I am getting the following error
error during connect: Post http://docker:2375/v1.40/auth: dial tcp: lookup docker on 192.168.0.1:53: no such host

I also tried setting the privileged = true, but still getting the same error. I have even added the entry in /etc/hosts as 192.168.0.1 docker too, but the output is still the same.
following is /etc/hots
ABC@XYZ:/var/run$ sudo cat  /etc/hosts
192.168.0.1     docker

Is there any configuration I am missing or need to rectify? Any help will be appreciated
